# Spliting Daterange values of jquery in two PHP variables

Tags: php

I am having a daterangepicker in form which grabs value in this format `10/12/2020 - 10/16/2020` i am passing this value using ajax to a PHP page for storing in Database. But I want to split daterange in to two variable for example from_date and to_date. i.e

```
$from_date = 2020-10-12;
$to_date = 2020-10-16;
```

I am not able to split these values in this format

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php) for this and for the formatting [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php) combined with [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php):

```
    $t = explode(' - ','10/12/2020 - 10/16/2020');
    
    var_dump($t);
    // array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "10/12/2020" [1]=> string(10) "10/16/2020" }

    $from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($t[0]));
    $to_date   = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($t[1]));

    echo $from_date;
    // 2020-10-12
```

Now you have

Comment: That is only half of it, they want the `10/12/2020` tranformed into `2020-10-12` as well.

Comment: `list($from, $to) = explode(' - ', '10/12/2020 - 10/16/2020');` is a bit easier.

Comment: Year, Month and Day also needs to be swapped. Please read the question carefully, before answering.

Comment: now all is good, sry for the previous answers, true I didn't read the question carefully !

Comment: I have also solved the issue with List function but this one seem simple